# Get vbe info struct in asm boot loader?

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I am creating an operating system and I want to get VBE info.
So I need to get [VbeInfoBlock](https://keeper.ktx.tw/xen/html/structVbeInfoBlock.html).

I need to do it in my bootloader, because to have this struct, it need to call BIOS in real mode.

To get VESA in C, I used https://wiki.osdev.org/VESA_Video_Modes

Comment: https://wiki.osdev.org/VESA_Video_Modes already tells you what asm `int 0x10` functions to use, and the exact struct layout.  `__attribute__ ((packed))` means no padding, so just the specified members in the specified order.

Comment: Thanks, but I don’t know how can I get segment and offset of thé struct

Comment: Allocate space for it somewhere; it can be anywhere, you just need a pointer to it.  Either statically, on the stack, or even with some kind of malloc-like function.  In a "tiny" memory model (with all segment regs equal), the pointer is just the offset.  It sounds like your real question is how to put a pointer in a register, which I thought had been answered in comments a few times on your previous questions.  But maybe there's some background knowledge about real-mode segmentation you're lacking that led to misunderstanding the answers. https://wiki.osdev.org/Segmentation#Real_mode